# random default thumbnail for blogger

Tags: html, css, thumbnails, default

i'm currently learning html and css. I'm working on a blogger blog template.

My template has a front page of post thumbnails.

I have set a class for my default thumbnail for when my posts do not have an image and I have set the url in the css.

```
.altthumbnails {
   background: url(myimagelocation.jpg);  
}
```

is there any way I can make more than one default thumbnail? I would like to chose maybe three images to show at random when there is no post image.

Thanks for any replies

Comment: with some `php` or `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it only with pure css. But you can do it either by the server-side code you use or js which the one I suggest. Basicly one of the easiest solution for this is you can make different classes for each different image you wanna use, then you can produce a random number in js and use this number to apply different classes to your elements. Here's an example:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wm5kX/)**

In the example there are 5 different css class that supply 5 different background-image and all their names end with numbers 1 >> 5.

```
.thumb_1 { .. }
.thumb_2 { .. }
.thumb_3 { .. }
.thumb_4 { .. }
.thumb_5 { .. }
```

In javascript we're gonna loop through the objects, generate a random number 1 >> 5 and use this number to add a new class like this.

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("thumb");

//var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 ); // for just one image

for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++){
   var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 ); // for multiple images
   div[i].className += " thumb_" + (rand + 1) ;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really interesting. I will work my way through it

Comment: I think i may need to greatly further my knowledge of js. I can see the principles of this though. Thanks again.